# Writing Curl Output to Batch File Variable

Tags: batch-file, curl, command-prompt

I am trying to get the total time to access a page and using this command:

```
curl -o NUL -s -w "%%{time_total}" http://stackoverflow.com
```

I am able to get the total time displayed in the command prompt.

However, now I would like to put this in a for loop like this:

```
echo off
SET /a i=0

:loop
IF %i%==10 GOTO END
echo Iteration %i%.
SET /a i=%i%+1
GOTO LOOP
:end
```

and sum up all the times I get, replacing `echo Iteration %i%.` with something like

```
set /a var = curl -o NUL -s -w "%%{time_total}" http://stackoverflow.com
set /a vartotal = var + vartotal
```

But of course this doesn't work, and I know its partially because the times returned are decimal and batch can't handle decimals.  Also, the URL may have non-alphabetic charcters in it such as ?, =, and &.  Please help

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is by redirecting the output of the result of the curl command to a file and the process that file.

It is a little bit more tricky because the number contains a comma (maybe a dot in your environment) and the command interpreter only does integer calculation and on my box it interpreted the number wrong. In addition if it the number started with a zero it assumed it was an OCTAL number so you have to strip that as well. Adding all this together would give you this command batch script:

```
set site=http://stackoverflow.com
set file=so.log
rem set this to , or . depending on your locale
set sep=,

set tot=0
del /Q %file%

rem add 10 values to the so.log file
for /L %%r in (1,1,10) do curl -o NUL -s -w "%%{time_total}\r\n" %site% >> %file%

rem read each line from the file
for /F %%a in (%file%) do  call :sum "%%a"

goto :end

rem sum procedure takes a number as first parameter
:sum
set milli=%1

IF "%sep%"=="," set val=%milli:,=%
IF "%sep%"=="." set val=%milli:.=%

set val2=%val:"=%

rem strip 0 if that is the first char
rem otherwise the number is 
rem considered to be octal
set lz=%val2:~0,1%
if @%lz%==@0 set val2=%val2:~1%

set /a "tot=tot+%val2%"

set milli=
set val=
set val2=

goto :EOF

:end
echo total time: %tot%

rem clean up
set sep=
set tot=
set site=
set file=
```